# How to run the rauth/flask example?

Tags: python, flask, rauth

I am trying to run the example:

```
https://github.com/litl/rauth/blob/master/examples/facebook/facebook.py
```

so I run this example from the command line and the output says:

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
* Restarting with reloader
```

and the program runs in the foreground. Now I thought let's see what happens when type the url in the browser:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

and it shows:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound
```

So I thought let's take a closer look into the source code and this is what I found:

```
Please note: you must do `from facebook import db; db.create_all()` from
the interpreter before running this example!
Due to Facebook's stringent domain validation, requests using this app
must originate from 127.0.0.1:5000.
```

So I thought may be I have to run this from the python shell. So I type the commands in python shell:

```
from facebook import db; db.create_all()
```

Now I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named facebook
```

So I thought may be I should install facebook. So I install it:

```
pip install facebook
```

which is a success. So then I run the command again from python shell:

```
from facebook import db; db.create_all()
```

now I get error:

```
Downloading/unpacking facebook.db
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement facebook.db
No distributions at all found for facebook.db
```

Now what? I am stuck. Please help someone.

Thanks

Comment: Two questions - 1) Have you got the [`templates` folder](https://github.com/litl/rauth/tree/master/examples/facebook/templates) checked out as well?  2) Were you running Python from the same directory that you had `facebook.py` checked out it? (`pip` most likely installed [this library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Facebook) which won't know how to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: You don't need a "facebook" module: that's a reference to the Flask application itself which happens to be named "facebook". Ensure you have a "templates" directory and that you run the db setup from the top-level facebook directory.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the pointer and quick response.